# SQL statement WHERE combined with AND and OR

Tags: sql

I want to update table headers' columns_header where field is equal to 'c02_Emissions' and field_base either 'VEHICLE' or 'VEHICLE_FP'. My current script updates all 'VEHICLE' and 'VEHICLE_FP' records and doesn't care about field = 'c02_Emissions'. This is not what I want. Can I get a bit of help on how to do it properly?

```
UPDATE headers
SET columns_header = 'CO2 Emissions'
WHERE field = 'c02_Emissions'
AND field_base = 'VEHICLE'
OR field_base = 'VEHICLE_FP';
```

Comment: AND goes before OR. Do `WHERE field = 'c02_Emissions'
AND (field_base = 'VEHICLE'
OR field_base = 'VEHICLE_FP');` Or use `IN`, i.e. `WHERE field = 'c02_Emissions'
AND field_base IN ('VEHICLE', 'VEHICLE_FP');`

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When combing AND's and OR's, you should always use parentheses:

```
UPDATE headers
SET columns_header = 'CO2 Emissions'
WHERE field = 'c02_Emissions'
AND (field_base = 'VEHICLE'
OR field_base = 'VEHICLE_FP');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this

```
UPDATE headers
SET columns_header = 'CO2 Emissions'
WHERE field = 'c02_Emissions'
AND field_base IN ( 'VEHICLE','VEHICLE_FP');
```

Comment: Isn't this just a copy-paste from the comment @jarlh added to the question?